# In the equivalent circuit of a PN junction diode, why is the battery shown in reverse?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I thought the positive terminal of the battery should correspond to the positive ions in the space charge region. But the polarity shown in the equivalent circuit is in reverse. May I know why this is the case ?

[image]

Comment: Please indicate, where you got this completely wrong information that a battery is part of the equivalent circuit of a pn-junction?

Answer (score 2):

This equivalent circuit is not quite complete - it needs an ideal diode, which, of course, signifies that the current in a diode could flow in one direction only.

[image]

It also shows that the battery is opposing the forward current in the diode and represents some sort of a barrier inside the diode that an external battery must overpower before any significant forward current can flow through the diode. This barrier explains the forward voltage drop in diodes.

Since all diodes behave that way, there is no question that the polarity of the battery in this equivalent circuit is correct. Why then does it seem to be opposite to the polarity of the space charge?

One way to explain it is that, for the forward current to flow, positive charges (holes) would have to cross the space charge region from left to right, which, as shown on the diagram, would be against the field or against an equivalent battery opposing the positive charges.

Similarly, negative charges (electrons) would have to cross the space charge region from right to left, which would be into the field and therefore they would be repelled and would have to overcome the same barrier from the opposite direction.

A possible alternative interpretation of the barrier, not directly involving the space charge, is that the electrons arriving to the n-region from a metal wire would have to move up the hill, to a higher energy level in the n-region, which could be interpreted as overcoming an energy barrier. The energy acquired by the electron in the process would be spent later, when the electron crosses the junction and re-combines with a hole.

Comment: A battery is never part of an equivalent circuit of a diode! This answer is not correct!

Comment: @freecharly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling. "Never" is a pretty strong word.

Comment: Sorry, you can have a circuit with a battery where a diode as part of the circuit, but a battery is never a part of an equivalent circuit of a pn-junction diode.  A normal pn-junction diode is a passive device that has only passive circuit elements. A voltage source (battery) would be an active element.

Comment: @freecharly If you get closer to the end of the article, you'll see a section describing diode modeling. Here a quote from this section: "The real diode is modelled as 3 components in series: an ideal diode, a voltage source and a resistor."

Comment: You are right, these are mathematical models for  piecewise linear characteristics, but I would not call them equivalent circuits. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_circuit

Comment: See also "piecewise linear approximation" in Wikipedia "Electrical Network": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_network

Comment: @freecharly Aside from terminology, you would probably agree that a model does not have to be more complex than is needed to analyze a problem at hand. A man standing on a scale could be perfectly modeled by a bunch of bricks, but we would not use bricks to model a man walking or jumping. The model we use here is adequate for discussing  the polarity of the forward voltage drop in a diode, but we would not use it for AC analysis.

Comment: I agree with you. But you have to distinguish between physical models and empirical mathematical approximations for a functional behavior of a device. The mathematical functional approximation here is an infinite step function for the I-V characteristic corresponding to a perfect switch.  The so-called "ideal diode" for circuit simulations is a switch that switches on at  $V_{appl}\geq 0$. For the functional approximation of a diode switching at a higher positive voltage, it would be better to assume a switch switching at this positive voltage (here 0.7V).

Comment: The introduction of an  "equivalent circuit" of an ideal diode switch  with an opposing battery voltage is unnecessary. I know that this misleading (equivalent circuit) model for the characteristics can be found in some simple (circuit) textbooks. I highly recommend not to use it. The mathematical functional model can, of course,  be used but it should not be related to a circuit model with a battery.

Comment: @freecharly Ok, we ran out of space here. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The battery absolutely doesn't belong to an equivalent circuit of a pn-junction diode. A diode is a passive device.

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling. "Absolutely" is a pretty strong word.

Comment: @V.F. - You have to understand that the equivalent circuit of a passive element like a normal pn-junction diode can never have a battery (voltage source) in it!

Comment: @freecharly  I think I see your point. Since we cannot drive a load using that battery,  it is not a real battery ? But is there a way to model diode with out using a battery ? If not,  how to best think of this fake battery ?

Comment: @rsadhvika - These are purely mathematical models, with device characteristics represented by a couple of straight lines, not models based in the physics pf the device. The "fake battery" is just the voltage where the assumed linear parts of the characteristics join. As you said such a "battery" would never deliver energy. The usual way to represent diodes by physical (large signal) models is for example the (exponential) Shockley diode equation, which gives a good approximation of the forward and reverse bias characteristics of a pn-junction and refinements of this model.

Comment: @rsadhvika - Such mathematical models using straight lines,  polynomials, or other mathematical function to describe a given current-voltage characteristic, are often used in (digital) circuit simulations. But it is highly misleading to represent such mathematical functions by a combination of "circuit elements" like in this mathematical straight lines  model of a diode. This wrongly suggests that the current in a diode starts to flow above a certain threshold voltage (0.7V ) which is an artifact of the mathematical straight lines approximation.

Comment: @freecharly  The fact that the battery in this equivalent circuit (or a model, if you prefer to call it a model) "would not deliver energy" does not mean that it cannot be used to to model diode's behavior. In this particular case, the battery actually consumes a fixed amount of energy per unit of forward current, which reasonably models what a diode does.

Comment: @V.F. - The question of rsadhvika looks for a connection between a misleading "circuit model" for a mathematical  function corresponding to an extremely rough approximation formula for the pn-diode I-V characteristics (used for simplified nonlinear (digital) **circuit simulations**)  to the **physics** of the pn-junction diode.  This is inappropriate because there is no such relation.  Such a "circuit model" for the shifted infinite step function characteristics is physically wrong and causes exactly the interpretation problems the OP has.

Comment: @V.F. - With a forward diode current, such a "battery" would be charging, storing an energy $E=I·V_{bat}·t$, which could, in principle, be recovered. In the real pn-junction diode only energy dissipation takes place according to Joule's law $E=V_{appl}·I·t$. There is no physical equivalent of a "battery" in a real pn-junction.